# How do I add a public tab or link for a Shopify Application Proxy

Tags: shopify

I have created an app that is intended to display content on the shop (not the admin).  I have created an application proxy so that my app is available through a url like:-

http://shopname.myshopify.com/apps/myApp

How can I expose this URL on the shop for users to click?  Ideally it would be visible in the store's main menu as another tab.

Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merchant will be able to go to `https://#{shop.myshopify_domain}/admin/links` and add that link. So you could instruct the merchant to add it themselves.

Unfortunately, at this time it doesn't look like these navigation links are API accessible, so you won't be able to add it automatically using your app.

Comment: exactly what I was going to suggest